# Any es6 method to un-escape an escaped html string?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to display the SVG using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:props.SVG_Thumbnail__c}} />`

However, the SVG data I got is an escaped HTML string.

I though this is a common case in Frontend. However, I did a google search none of built-in method could handle all the escaped chars perfectly.

The escape method doesn't work.

What's a common way to handle this string?

Write the replace methods every time?

```
     var escaped = str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                 .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                 .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');




    &lt;svg width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;100%&q%&quot; fill=&quot;#ffffff&quot;/&gt;&lt;text x=&quot;5%&quot; y=&quot;50%&quot; font-family=&quot;Lato&quot; font-size=&quot;8px&quot; alignment-baseline=&quot;middle&quot; fill=&quot;#37444e&quot;&gt;Primary Content&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;&lt;svg x=&quot;10%&quot; y=&quot;64%&quot; width=&quot;90%&quot; height=&quot;26%&quot;&gt;&lt;rect x=&quot;0&quot; y=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;100%&quot; fill=&quot;#ffffff&quot;/&gt;&lt;text x=&quot;5%&quot; y=&quot;50%&quot; font-family=&quot;Lato&quot; font-size=&quot;8px&quot; alignment-baseline=&quot;middle&quot; fill=&quot;#37444e&quot;&gt;Secondary Content&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is assign the escaped value to an HTML element's `innerHTML` property, and then use the `textContent` property to get it back in unescaped form.

```js
function unescapeHtml(value) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = value;
    return div.textContent;
}

var escapedValue = '&lt;svg width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;100%&q%&quot; fill=&quot;#ffffff&quot;/&gt;&lt;text x=&quot;5%&quot; y=&quot;50%&quot; font-family=&quot;Lato&quot; font-size=&quot;8px&quot; alignment-baseline=&quot;middle&quot; fill=&quot;#37444e&quot;&gt;Primary Content&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;&lt;svg x=&quot;10%&quot; y=&quot;64%&quot; width=&quot;90%&quot; height=&quot;26%&quot;&gt;&lt;rect x=&quot;0&quot; y=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;100%&quot; fill=&quot;#ffffff&quot;/&gt;&lt;text x=&quot;5%&quot; y=&quot;50%&quot; font-family=&quot;Lato&quot; font-size=&quot;8px&quot; alignment-baseline=&quot;middle&quot; fill=&quot;#37444e&quot;&gt;Secondary Content&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;';

var unescapedValue = unescapeHtml(escapedValue);

console.log(unescapedValue);
```

Comment: Cool. I'm just wondering this common case doesn't have any out-of-box method to handle it ^^. thanks

Comment: @newBike None that I'm aware of.